# How to read from a file in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I have this desktop application I am working on that should keep track of small comments of certain things. The idea is to have a savefiledialog for saving files and and openfiledialog for opening  files. But in the openToolStripMenuItem_Click method I have trouble reading from a file and setting the textbox1.Text to the file being read to and opening the text in the file to be edited for small comments. Here is the code below

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog fo = new OpenFileDialog();
    fo.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    fo.ShowDialog();
    if (File.Exists(fo.FileName)) 
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fo.FileName,Encoding.UTF8)) {
                textBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();   
            }

    }
}
```

this works fine

```
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fo.FileName,Encoding.UTF8)) {
                        textBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();   
                    }
```

and so does this

```
    textbox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(fo.FileName);
```

EDIT: There was nothing in the file I was opening.

Comment: You mention you have "trouble reading from file & setting the textbox1"
What trouble exactly?

Comment: When asking question that exactly matches MSDN article title like [How to: Read From a Text File C# ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx) consider linking to the article and clarify what exactly is not clear.

Comment: When I read from a file and set the value from textbox1.Text to a StreamReader object method or File.Open i get  a System.IO.StreamReader or nothing at all, inside the textbox instead of the actual file contents.

Comment: It's worth your while to learn how to use the return type of methods to your advantage. The return type of File.OpenText is a StreamReader - you could Google 'StreamReader' and find out how to use one. Hint: ToString() isn't useful. Look at the answers to this question, the MSDN link provided, or the question this is marked as a duplicate of. All will help you here.

Comment: ... You *can* use StreamReader, just not like that.

Comment: I tried several different ways . I just happened to post one of the things I tried

Comment: Its still is not working...

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicated to the other question marked. It isn't about reading file contents. Its about using the OpenFileDialog API to read the file contents.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`System.IO.File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read all of the contents of a file into a string.

Comment: Everytime I open the file through the file dialog nothing shows in the textbox

Answer (score 1):

File.OpenText will return you an StreamReader, that's a class for manipualting text streams, it's not the text content on the file.

If you want to read it then use File.ReadAllText(yourFIle), it will return just a string with the content of the file.